# Duplicate entry unique key.... my error catching failed

Tags: google-app-maker

So I am updating something but I only want it to make a record for new records.

```
 for (var i=0; i<allquery.length;i++)
    {
    var oldrecord = allquery[i];
    var newrecord = app.models.xx.newRecord();
    newrecord.gPor = xxString;
    newrecord.UniqueNumber = oldrecord.Unique;
      newrecord.Name = oldrecord.dname;      
    try{app.saveRecords([newrecord]);//this is line 30            
    results.push(newrecord);}catch(e){Logger.log (e+ " "+oldrecord.dname);}     

    }//for loop
```

I'm frustrated because the sql error should be caught in the try catch (it is appearing for the saveRecords line... but instead it is killing the script. Thoughts? do I need to implement manual save mode? (which will require rewriting elsewhere.

The error is:

> Exception: Malformed SQL. More information: Error with SQL statement:
>   Duplicate entry '0270' for key 'UniqueNumber_unique'. at
>   createApprovals (ApprovalBugScripts:30)

Comment: The logic you are using is forcing to create duplicates. If you want to update something, then don't create a new record. Instead just update the old record. If you create a new record, then don't assign an old record `Unique` to the new one.

Comment: Never mind my earlier comment. I think what you want to happen is if the save record function fails then you want the catch statement to execute which will log your already existing record 'dname' field in the console. Keep in mind that unlike regular apps script, Logger will not work in AM, you actually have to use console.log on server in AM. Also, unlike Apps Script, any actions involving Server API will throw an error on the line where it is first encountered, so the saveRecords throws the error due to duplicate record and the catch portion is never executed.

Comment: From what I'm gathering from your process it appears that you are expecting your old database or old model to have duplicate Unique IDs or that your batch processing may involve records that were previously processed in an other batch? It seems to me that you could instead run a query in your 'xx' model for each loop iteration to see if oldrecord.Unique already exists and if it does then run the console log.

Comment: Thanks markus, I think that last suggestion would work (yes, i'm reimporting data that has been imported before butI don't want to overwrite my changes from post original import).

Comment: But what also worked was putting the entire make a new record loop into the try catch, not just the save/push).

Answer (score 1):

Enclosing the entire creation part in a try catch worked:

```
 for (var i=0; i<allquery.length;i++)
    {
try{
    var oldrecord = allquery[i];
    var newrecord = app.models.xx.newRecord();
    newrecord.gPor = xxString;
    newrecord.UniqueNumber = oldrecord.Unique;
      newrecord.Name = oldrecord.dname;      
    app.saveRecords([newrecord]);//this is line 30            
    results.push(newrecord);}catch(e){Logger.log (e+ " "+oldrecord.dname);}     

    }//for loop
```